# Sklearn SVR shows worst result after scaling

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

Following code works quite well when used without scaling, but when scaling is applied results are too far from actual. Here is the code:

```
 data =(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63).
   model = SVR(kernel='poly', C=1e3, degree=3)
   data_min =  min(data)
   data_max = max(data)
   diff = data_max - data_min
   data_scaled = []
   for i in range(0,len(data)):
      data_scaled.append((data[i]-data_min)/diff)

   data_scaled = np.matrix(data_scaled)
   data_scaled = data_scaled.reshape(-1,1)
   y = (1,8,27,64,125,216,343,512,729,1000,1331,1728,2197,2744,3375,4096,4913,5832,6859,8000,9261,10648,12167,13824,15625,17576,19683,21952,24389,27000,29791,32768,35937,39304,42875,46656,50653,54872,59319,64000,68921,74088,79507,85184,91125,97336,103823,110592,117649,125000,132651,140608,148877,157464,166375,175616,185193,195112,205379,216000,226981,238328,250047)
   model.fit(data_scaled, y)
   predicted = model.predict(data_scaled)
```

Comment: You seem to have only a single feature ("data"). Scaling should be unnecessary here. Besides, I would use StandardScaler, available in preprocessing module. Last but not least, checking accuracy on your training data is in general very poor idea.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, actually here I am just trying to experiment and check how it will regression performs. When I did the above regression without scaling results are coming quite good, I just want to know why results are varying after applying scaling.

Comment: Can you show us to totality of your code, specially the metric of error, because in my case, the error is getting better

Comment: It seems to me both scaled and raw data should return equally good or crappy results, depending on the kernel. Please verify it. As @RachidAitAbdesselam was saying, you need to put your complete code. BTW - by default SVR uses RBF kernel which will get you very poor results. Use 'poly'.

Comment: Sorry for late response. I have updated kernel information in the code. Let me know your suggestion.